# How to modify a program to output the summation of an equation

Tags: javascript

Hi for one of my labs it is trying to tell me to do tasks such as, modifying 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10= to output the summation, while also keeping it in one line rather than cascading down the page. This is what i have so far and i dont know how to finish it.

```
var y= ""
for ( x = 0; x < 11; x++ ) {
    y+= x + "+" + "";
}
console.log(y);
```

EDIT

```
var sum = 0;
var y = "";

for (x = 0; x < 11; x++) {
    y += x + "+" + "";
    sum += x;
}
console.log(y, sum);
```

Comment: Try `var sum = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < 11; x++) {
    sum += x;
}
console.log(sum);`

Comment: the only thing that shows up is 55, i need this included 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=

Comment: `var sum = 0,
    eq = [];

for (var x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
    sum += x;
    eq.push(x);
}
console.log(sum);
console.log(eq.join(' + ') + ' = ' + sum);`

Comment: how can we do it without the eq. and eq push

Answer (score 3):

try like this

```
var y= ""
var temp=[]
for ( x = 0; x < 10; x++ ) {
    temp.push(x+1);
}

y=temp.join('+');
var sum=temp.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;});
y+='='+sum
console.log(y);
```

EDIT

for more simple

```
var y = ""
var sum=0;
var n = 10;
for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    var val=(+x + 1);
    sum += val;
    y += val;
    if (x < n - 1) y += '+';
}
y+='='+sum;
console.log(y);
```

suppose you have sequence

```
n=5
```

means `1+2+3+4+5=15`

```
n= 4
```

means `1+2+3+4=10`

Everytime after nth `+` is not repated

That's why `if (x < n - 1)` won't add `+` when `x=4` as you are using `x` from `0`

Comment: all that shows in the console is \1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11

Comment: wow thats amazing, but is there a simpler way to portray this because i'm in beginner web prgramming

Comment: the lab only wants us to use  a for loop

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Just add some explanation with code as OP is noob, that'll help him understand code

Comment: last + is conditional you have to remove it with condition or substring or split .. whatever you choose @Demoman09

Comment: @Demoman09 i have added some explanation that might help you .

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
var out= "";
var sum=0;
for ( var i = 1; i < 11; i++ ) {
    out+=(i===1?""+i:"+"+i);
    sum=sum+i;
}
console.log(out+"="+sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo:

```js
var i = 1;
var out = '';
var sum = 0;
while (10 >= i) {
  out += '+' + i;
  sum += i ++;
}
out += '=' + sum;
out = out.substr(1);//remove the first `+`
document.write(out);
```